# Dot multiply between a matrix and column vector in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do a ***dot*** multiplication between a matrix 4x4 and a vector 4x1 in C#.
If I try with  `using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;`

```
Matrix<double>.op_DotMultiply(matrixABuilder.DenseOfArray(A), matrixPBuilder.DenseOfArray(P));
```

Where `A` is a matrix of `4x4` and `P` defined as `4x1`, I'm getting the next error>
`System.ArgumentException: 'Matrix dimensions must agree: op1 is 4x4, op2 is 4x1. (Parameter 'other')'`

If I convert from matrix `P` to a vector and then calculate (now `P` is a vector of `double[]`)>

`Matrix<double>.op_DotMultiply(matrixA.DenseOfArray(A),vectorPBuilder.Dense(P));`

then I get the error that

`Cannot convert from 'MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Vector<double>' to 'MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Matrix<double>'`

How I must get an result for this type of multiplication, to get as result an array of `4x1` data? (In Python the numpy.dot() is working fine, in C# not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dot` multiplication needs equal sized `Matrix`es and computes single double value.
It seems that you need actually multiplication of matrix to vector.
Convert `P` to `Vector` and simply use `*` for multiplication:

```cs
matrixABuilder.DenseOfArray(A) * vectorPBuilder.Dense(P)
```

Comment: So in this case, when we want to multiply a matrix with a vector, the dot product is the same as simply multiplication?

Comment: Yes, if you want `dot` multiplication of 4x4 on 4x1 and get 4x1 - this is just matrix on vector multiplication.

Comment: Do you know what should I do when I have multiplication for 4x4 and 4x2 ?